# How to convert calculated column in spotfire to Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to add a calculated column in Power BI Using calculated column from spotfire

**Cal_column = Rank([Custom ID], [App Id])**

Help me with concerting this to DAX.
Thanks in advance

Sample result looks like 
**Rank Custom ID App Id**
 1    1306450   373197
                        5367590
 4     1308326  383990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following calculation:

```
Rank = 
VAR CurrentSelection = Max(Table[CustomID])
RETURN
RANKX(FILTER(All(Table),Table[CustomID]=CurrentSelection),Table[AppID],,DESC,Dense)
```

You can also refer to the video to understand the basics of ranking in Power BI:
https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerBI/comments/ae7ntp/rank_by_multiple_columns_in_rankx_measure/

Edit:

```
Rank = 
RANKX(ALLSELECTED(Table),CALCULATE(MIN(Table[CustomID]),ALLEXCEPT(Table,Tale[AppID])),,DESC,Dense)
```

Comment: In the previous data set we are getting rank values from 1 to 43 , but if we use the above dax code we are just getting 1,2

Comment: I have added an edit in the answer...Try it and let me know

Comment: I tried it , now I am getting rank values more than 1000